# How can I call a method when a key is typed?

Tags: ios, ipad, ios4

Is there a way to call a method each time a user types on the onscreen keyboard?  For example, a method is called when the user always hits the w key and a different method for the s key.  Or will I need to create my own keyboard for the user to use?

This will be for the iPad.

Answer (score 1):

First create a subclass of `UIResponder` (e.g. a `UIView` or `UIViewController`) and have it adopt the `UIKeyInput` protocol (and implement the required methods). Then make it first responder. The method `insertText:` will be called for each key.

Caveat: Not all keyboards are supported (e.g. Japanese, Simplified Chinese).